# Rocket Thrust vs Air breathing jet engine why is a rocket better

Tags: jet-engine, turbojet, rocket, ramjet, scramjet

What are design dynamics that give the rocket engine higher thrust than an air breathing jet engine of similar size in comparison to a turbo jet engine, turbo fan engine, high by pass turbo fan engine, Scram jet or ram jet.  Is it impossible to improve any of these engines to match the performance of the rocket in terms of thrust

Comment: Your question seems too broad. I fail to understand if it concerns speed limitation of air-breathing jet engine, designs comparision for supersonic engines (either rockets or air-breathing jet engine), thrust limitation, or something else. You should refine your question so that it is more specific. Don't hesitate to take a tour in the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply the rate at which fuel can be burned.  For instance, the Saturn V's first stage carried 1.37 million kg of liquid oxygen (along with the kerosene fuel), which it burned in about 165 seconds.  Imagine the size of the jet intake you'd need for a comparable amount of air.